# Tax on Shipping not on mi dashboard MGT 1.8.1

Tags: shipping, configuration, tax, dashboard, magento-go

I reed manual for setup tax on shipping [Tax on Shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-tax-on-shipping#scenario3) and I can not find the parameters indicating the manual.

Manual speak about "Flat Tax Rate on Taxable Cart" but i don't see this question on any manual, or on my dashboard and I don't see **"Tax on Shipping"** on **System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax**

I don't know if this it's a bug, a error in the manual, a different version ...

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Magento Go does not exist anymore

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Magento Go - Tax on Shipping was supplied by WebShopApps to Magento for Go.  It is not in Magento CE.